# Ubuntu 18.04 can't boot (emergency mode)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, swap

After shutting down the PC too many times while the kernel is loading my Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't boot anymore. It falls into emergency mode the grub wasn't showing before:`

[image]

The black screen after I select Ubuntu from the grub boot menu:

[image: the screen after I select Ubuntu from the grub]

I ran `journalctl -xb` and this is what I got:

[image: error1]

[image: error 2]

I don't know what's causing these errors, but after reading some questions here I think that the problem is related to disk partitions.
after running `cat /etc/fstab`:

[image: after running cat /etc/fstab]

after running `lsblk -f`:

[image: after running lsblk -f]

Comment: Looks like you damaged your filesystem. That can happen when you shutdown uncleanly (don't do that anymore). Look up how to run `fsck` to repair your filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, and it took me a bit of time to realize it was due to a bad entry in my `/etc/fstab`... I was setting up multiple OSes on different partitions, and at some point one of the partitions' UUID changed, so when I booted a previously working OS, it failed because it didn't find the UUID defined in /etc/fstab.

To fix it I simply commented out using `#` the unmountable partition, then rebooted. I later was able to remount the desired partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. enter root password.
2. enter mount -a to see where the error is (which line).
3. enter nano  /etc/fstab and comment the missing or uncomment it then save and finally reboot. (for example: 
   comment a line like this  UUID =0E52-654D /boot/efi)
4. enter reboot